# Есть ли в WinUI аналог UWP .NET Native?

Tags: c#, winui3

Есть ли такая утилита? Встроенный ReadyToRun ни на что не годится. Графическая часть приложения очень медленная. Нет той быстроты и плавности как в UWP.

Comment: R2R - это только на загрузку бинарника в память влияет, но никак не на работу. Если у вас тупит интерфейс, возможно вы где-то неправильно с ним работаете. Я пока практики много с WinUI 3 не имею, но как воспроизвести ту проблему, о которой вы говорите - понятия не имею, у меня все работает без тормозов, не хуже, чем когда-то тащил WPF. Плюс сама XAML библиотека Windows App SDK (вы про нее же говорите) вообще на C++ написана и является априори Native, то есть все что вы видите на экране - рисуется native кодом. Проверьте нагрузку на свой UI поток, быть может где-то облегчить получится.

Comment: По поводу прямого ответа про аналог - ответ "нет", но скорее всего будет. Сейчас .NET 7 активно пилит поддержку нативной компиляции, но область применения пока до UI приложений не дошла.

Comment: *"Нет той быстроты и плавности как в UWP."* - я чуть со стула не упал. Потрясает, как запросто может выходить настолько убогое и тормозное ПО, что на его фоне прежнее убогое и тормозное ПО кажется шустрым...

Comment: У меня два совершенно (100%) одинаковых приложения. Одно на UWP, другое на Windows App SDK написанно. UWP в разы плавнее работает, на этом приложении просто приятно работать. А вот приложение на Windows App SDK не имеет той плавности и мягкости. Все как бы работает, но "кайф" работы с приложением уже не тот.

Comment: Эти детали не говорят примерно ни о чем. Создайте воспроизводимый пример, где видна разница между WinUI 2 и WinUI 3.